# Quarkus - no error but no email (with gmail)

Tags: java, quarkus

i'm trying to send email with quarkus with this guide  https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer#gmail-specific-configuration.

I use this code :

```
@Inject
Mailer mailer;

@GET
public Response sendMailTest() {
   mailer.send(Mail.withHtml("<mail gmail>", "A simple email from quarkus", "<p>This is my body.<p>"));
   return Response.accepted().build();
}
```

with this parameters :

```
quarkus.mailer.auth-methods=DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-SHA256 CRAM-SHA1 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
quarkus.mailer.from=<mail gmail>
quarkus.mailer.host=smtp.gmail.com
quarkus.mailer.port=465
quarkus.mailer.ssl=true
quarkus.mailer.username=<mail gmail>
quarkus.mailer.password=<app gmail password>
```

I haven't some error but i haven't some mail. The app password gmail has configured for this usecase ...

Anybody has any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: For your reference https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2021/09/quarkus-how-to-send-email-via-smtp.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read this ?

quarkus.mailer.mock

Enables the mock mode, not sending emails. The content of the emails is printed on the console. Disabled by default on PROD, enabled by default on DEV and TEST modes.

Have you tested this by running your app as a standalone jar ?

Comment: Hello, i didn't see this variable. But i have the same with unit test. 

[quarkus-mailer] (vert.x-worker-thread-6) Sending email A simple email from quarkus from xxx to [xxx], text body: 
null
html body: 
<p>This is my body.<p>

i tryed to past by sendgrid or mailjet but i haven't mail. I tryed to past by ssl or not but always no mail.

Comment: In testing mode, Quarkus automatically uses the mock mail  mode. Only when you are using the production profile it will try to send real mails.
If you want to disable the mock mode in your test then you have to set quarkus.mailer.mock=false in /src/test/resources/application.properties.

Comment: oh i knew that my error was too easy ... thank you ! i only used this for a test, so always in dev mode.

Answer (score 2):

in .properties, use the parameter

```
quarkus.mailer.mock=false
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).