# Quarkus Gmail Setup

Tags: ssl, quarkus, mailing

Getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection` while trying to setup quarkus for Mailing system.

I'm new to quarkus. I have been trying to setup a mail service using this as reference - https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference#gmail-specific-configuration

I have configured my application.yml as

```
quarkus:
  mailer:
    auth-methods: DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-SHA256 CRAM-SHA1 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
    from: mymail@gmail.com
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 465 # For ssl
    ssl: true
    username: "mydevmail@gmail.com"
    password: "generated password"
    mock: false
```

Bear in mind, I have **2FA enabled.** I followed this article to enable generated passwords as well allowing smtp for gmail - https://mailmeteor.com/blog/gmail-smtp-settings

I was unable to send any mail at all. After reading stack overflow post - [Quarkus - no error but no email (with gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185158/quarkus-no-error-but-no-email-with-gmail) I was able to proceed with one step further.

Now, in my final step, I found this additional issue with SSL -

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection`

I did try with TLS too by changing `quarkus.mailer.port` to **587** and **removing** `quarkus.mailer.ssl`. But then I find this error -
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Can someone explain me why I'm getting the issue? And what could be the possible fixes to this.

**Edit**: I am quite inexperienced with ssl. So apologies if it sounds stupid. I did generate a `pem` file in resources using command
 `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > google-smtp-ca.pem`

The command is stuck with log as below and an empty file `google.smtp-ca.pem`.

```
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = smtp.gmail.com
verify return:1
250 SMTPUTF8
```

additional `application.yml` config I have configured

```
quarkus:
  ssl:
    truststore:
      file: google-smtp-ca.pem
```

I am using windows 11.

Comment: you need to import(keytool) that pem to your jdk as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76899123/175554)

Comment: Thanks. that helped. This fixed `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection` that appeared before. I am no longer seeing this exception.

Comment: I'm still stuck with further issues. Which I'm not sure if related.
The API is reaching the send mail implementation and is taking forever to process. This is the dummy service I have used.
```
@Singleton
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MailService {
    private final Mailer mailer;

    public void sendMail() {
        mailer.send(Mail.withText("mymail@gmail.com"
                , "Greeting Subject",
                "Greeting Body"));
    }
}
```

Quarkus doesn't even log any issues.

Comment: apologies. I think removing the configuration `quarkus.mailer.ssl` from the application.yml file actually stopped the exception from occuring anymore, not the keytool import. And removing this results in the forever loading api without any results.